# Why is the price of any asset divided by a reference asset(numeraire) is a martingale under the measure associated with that numeraire?

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-processes, martingale

why is the price of any asset divided by a reference asset(numeraire) is a martingale under the measure associated with that numeraire?

For example, if I have the price of a forward price $f_t$ and a zero-coupon bond price $B_t$, then $\frac{f_t}{B_t}$ would be martingale under the measure $Q^B$.

Comment: The theorem runs in the other direction: for any asset S and any reference asset N (subject to some mild mathematical conditions) we can find a measure Q such that under this measure the stochastic process S/N is a martingale. It is not: "look I discovered that S/N is a martingale!" it is "look they gave me S and N and I found a Q that will make S/N a martingale"

Comment: The cumulative dividend plus the discounted price is a martingale. Essentially this is because when you reinvest the dividends to buy new assets you have a non dividend paying asset. For some maths about this see [this recent question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/68515/how-to-derive-forward-price-on-stock-with-continuous-dividend/68520#68520).

Comment: A Martingale corresponds to the common notion that "an efficient price changes randomly" so we cannot know if it will go up or down. That is why this mathematical concept is brought into Finance by P.A. Samuelson and others.