# Dividend adjustment on SABR formula for interpolating implied volatility

Tags: implied-volatility, sabr, interpolation, volatility-interpolation

We are using a SABR model to interpolate the implied volatility surface.
The model yields a formula for implied volatility that contains the following term:

$\ln \left(\frac{K}{F}\right)$

It is proposed to take into account cash dividends by modifying this part of the equation to:

$\ln \left(\frac{K+D}{F+D}\right)$

$D$ is Dividend adjustment for maturity $t$

$F$ is the forward contract value for maturity $t$

$K$ is the Strike value

Can you please explain the rationale of such a modification in the formula in order to take into account cash dividends?

Comment: My answers to [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/68515/how-to-derive-forward-price-on-stock-with-continuous-dividend/68520#68520) and [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/68916/gbm-how-to-make-make-annualized-dividend-reflected-in-one-quarter/68922#68922) question show how to incorporate dividends into a forward for the stock. I do not quite understand why it was proposed that $D$ should also be added to the strike $K$. Also the sign of $D$ matters a lot. Is your $D$ positive or negative?

Comment: From the forward we usually ***subtract*** the dividends that are due between now and the time of the forward.