# Cost of carry proof

Tags: futures, forward, continuous-time

I'm currently review Arbitrage Pricing in Continuous time by Bjork and am stuck on this concept:

[image]

Honestly I'm not too sure where to start as this chapter makes no mention of the Cost of Carry formula for dividend paying assets ( and I am not having any luck online either ).

Thanks

Comment: Simply put the cost of carry is the financing cost minus the present value of dividends.

Comment: As far as I can tell that Hint asks to use the cost of carry formula to show another cost of carry formula. Confusion enough to forget about it. I recommend to develop everything from [first principles](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/68922/58786) without reading too much stuff. The formula you want to show corresponds to (3) in my answer.